# How to use Javascript in GAE?

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine

I'm trying to use Javascript in my GAE app.

I'm trying to see if it'll work with a simple example:

```
  <script language="javascript" type="text⁄javascript">
  function myFunction()
  {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Date();
  }
  </script>
```

This doesn't work.

I've tried searching for a solution, but I couldn't find anything. Maybe it's too simple?

I'm sure I'm missing a step some where. Thank you.

Comment: Where is this code? How are you loading it into your HTML page? Is the file getting loaded? How are you calling it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same way you would use JavaScript everywhere, try the bellow and see if you see anything, because the code that you posted doesn't do much as is.

```
<script>
    alert("Hello World!");
</script>
```

In order to use static files you will have to spend some time reading the docs and you could start with the [simple example](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/staticfiles) from the tutorial.